# Rules for naming POST/GET variables?

Tags: html, http, post, get

Are there any rules one needs to follow when naming POST variables in a form or GET variables in a query string?

Thanks-

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TO answer the question literally, there really are no "rules" I'm aware of for naming `$_POST` and `$_GET` array keys in php. It's an array like any other. Take a look at [this working example on Codepad](http://codepad.org/rPv4KxG1):

```
<?php
$_POST['♠♣♥♦'] = 'value1';
$_POST['\'\'\'\''] = 'value2';
$_POST['<?php echo "Hello World"; ?>'] = 'value3';
$_POST['     '] = 'value4';
$_POST[''] = 'value5';
$_POST['@#$%^&*()'] = 'value6';

print_r($_POST);
```

In the case of form input names, they just have to be legal HTML "name" attributes (see below). However, in practice, a lot of unusual characters will actually work. Keep in mind that this doesn't mean it's a good idea. Different servers (and probably different browsers) will act differently with some characters like spaces for instance.

As [Tadeck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943957/rules-for-naming-post-get-variables/5944013#5944013) has noted, duplicate keys will be overwritten by the last one when reading, but using `brackets[]` will solve this on the client side by turning the variable into an array.

As far as naming conventions and best practices, there isn't a lot of room. It's suggested that you stick to A-Z a-z 0-9, dashes, and underscores. Although [Ajay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943957/rules-for-naming-post-get-variables/5944174#5944174) has suggested using database column names for form input names as a matter of convenience, many people will tell you that it is bad practice to expose information about your database to the public. I think [invertedlambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943957/rules-for-naming-post-get-variables/5947488#5947488) probably has the closest answer here to the question, and [Tadeck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943957/rules-for-naming-post-get-variables/5944013#5944013) has the closest answer as far as best practices.

Regarding HTML "name" attributes: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.2

> **ID** and **NAME** tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Maybe someone can enlighten me as to whether or not the above document is a rule or a recommendation, I'm by no means an expert on this subject. I seem to have no issues breaking some of these rules in practice. I also have no problem validating this example document as XHTML strict:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<div><form action="" method="post">
<div>
<input name="♠♣♥♦" />
<input name="''''" />
<input name=")(&amp;#$)%#$%" />
</div>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Paste it into [the validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input), it will pass.

---

One more best practice to add: Make your form input names or get/post keys meaningful, as with every other naming convention of course. Don't use `input1` and `$_GET['param']`. Use names that describe the meaning, like `last_name` or `$_GET['sort_order']`.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the best solution is to:

- use lower cases,
- NOT use dots, any other special characters (undescores are acceptable),
- understand the way they are passed during request (eg. `name="test[][]"` will create value within array that is within other array) and use it properly,
- avoid creating conflicts (eg. `?test=1&test=2` will create problems as only one of the values will be passed - better use `?test[]=1&test[]=2` so the array with two values will be passed),
- be consistent,

Furthermore, browse through different solutions that you may find on [GitHub.com](http://www.github.com/) so you will be using practices that are good, tested and used by many people.

Comment: These aren't all really rules, some are your opinions.

Comment: @Wesley Correct. The first one does not need to be followed. This is what you had in mind?

Comment: Aren't some of these language/framework dependent? I.e. the third and fourth one (Django, for examples, handles identical query keys just fine).

Comment: I think that is why you should not write it in a way supported by one language and not supported by other. Don't you think? Also Yarin did not give us any tip regarding the language that will be used to interpret POST / GET (probably on server side, but not necessarily).

Comment: "dots, any other special characters" are completely fine. Spaces are fine. Dashes are fine. To OP's question: GET variables in a query string can contain anything, but will (should) be encoded.

Comment: Ok, I am convinced. Please add your answer - I will delete mine and vote for yours to ensure everyone who reaches that question is not given something misleading.

Comment: I was thinking of classes and ids, I think there may be different rules for **name** attributes, but different than you mentioned, and not applicable literally to post/get. See my answer and please comment if you find something awry.

Answer (score 4):

In a word, no -- as long as your variable names are compliant with the HTTP specification and the backing web server that you're using, you can call your parameters anything you want.

If you use the same guidelines for naming a parameter as you use when you name variables, you should be able to pick a good name.

Answer (score -1):

We can use the names as like variable names rules , but can use the keywords also as GET/POST Variable names.
Better we can use the same names as database column names where ever applicable. But there is no rule like this.
Just these are some recommendations.

Comment: Exposing database column names to the wild is generally not a recommendation.

Comment: @Wesley Thanks, that is true, thank for clarification. In case of Get we can use good names which will be suitable for Search engines for optimization like using keywords.