# insert data into the database

Tags: php, codeigniter

Its my controller code`

```
class Booking_Controller extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct(){

        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Books_model');

    }

public function view()
{


    $data['result']=$this->Books_model->get_restaurants();

    $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
    $this->load->view('restaurants/booking',$data);

    $this->Books_model->insert_into_db();

}


}
```

Books_model`code is

```
<?php

class Books_model extends CI_Model{

public function __construct(){

    $this->load->database();

}

public function get_restaurants()
{
    $sql = "SELECT restaurant_id, names FROM restaurants ";
    $query = $this->db->query( $sql );
    return $query->result();

}

public function insert_into_db()
{
   $people =$this->input->post('No.of. People');
   return $this->db->insert('reservation',$people);

}

}
```

view code

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url();?>Booking_Controller/view" method="post">

                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>number of people</td>
                    <td>number of people = <input type = 'text' name='No.of. People'></td>
                        </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type='submit' value="Submit"></td>

                    </tr>
                </table>
                </form>
```

the problem is that when i run the project it give me this error...

A Database Error Occurred
You must use the "set" method to update an entry.

plz guide me where i did mistake

`

Comment: this isn't a good name and PHP might be complaining about it `name='No.of. People'` use underscores `name='No_of_People'`. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: Just little add to comment above is answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943957/rules-for-naming-post-get-variables#answer-5952726). You will find that blank space is not allowed. But for sake of simplicity and easy consistency, use @Fred-ii naming convention example.

Answer (score 0):

Per CodeIgniter documenation the insert command's second parameter should be an array (or an object), not a string.

So if you are inserting into a table named `reservation` and the column being inserted is `total` then you would use the function below:

```
public function insert_into_db()
{
   $people =$this->input->post('No.of. People');
   return $this->db->insert('reservation', array('total'=>$people));

}
```

Also like Fred mentioned in the comments, you should use a better name for your input box. Between these two things it should resolve your problem.

Comment: thanx 4 reply... i follow your code. but now i get this error                          Error Number: 1048

Column 'no_of_people' cannot be null

INSERT INTO `reservation` (`no_of_people`) VALUES (NULL)

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/book/application/models/Books_model.php

Line Number: 26 ....plz guide me what i do....